# Cypress tests integration with Xray (Jira) through Github

Tags: github, cypress, github-actions, x-ray, jira-xray

I hope you all are doing good. As, the title suggest what I am trying to do is I have e2e tests in cypress and I want them to be integrated with test management tool xray that we have in Jira (Write tests in cypress, execute them in CI i.e. github and send results to test management tool i.e. Xray). We are using github for development purpose. So, if anyone has experience or can point me in the direction on how to do this integration. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

let me share some tutorials that exemplify how you can integrate with Xray.
The first thing you need to find is whether you're using Xray on Jira Cloud or Xray on Jira server/datacenter, as they're different products and the APIs are slightly different.

If you're using Xray on Jira Cloud, please check:

- https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Testing+using+Cypress+in+JavaScript
- https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Testing+using+Cypress+and+Cucumber+in+JavaScript

If you're using Xray on Jira server/datacenter, please check:

- https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+using+Cypress+in+JavaScript
- https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+using+Cypress+and+Cucumber+in+JavaScript

Comment: @hamza, was my answer able to clarify your question? If so, can you please mark my answer as correct? Otherwise, please let me know, so I can see I can help you further